# using Imputer in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, missing-data, imputation

I need to fill the missing temperature value with the mean value of that month using `Imputer()` in scikit-learn.

First I split the dataframe into groups based on the month.  Then I called the imputer function to calculate the mean for that group and fill in the missing values.

Here is the code I wrote but it didn't work:

```
def impute_missing (data_1_group):
    imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
    imp.fit(data_1_group)
    data_1_group=imp.transform(data_1_group['datetime'])
    return(data_1_group)

for data_1_group in data_1.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper("M")):
    impute_missing(data_1_group)
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: *Here is the code I wrote but it didn't work.*  How did it not work?  What is the exact error?

Comment: this is what I got                                                                               TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Comment: Now I changed it to :                                                                        grouped = data_1.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper("M"))
f = lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean())
transformed = grouped['temperature'].transform(f)   and I got TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: So this question really isn't about the Imputer, it's about the groupby method?

Answer (score 1):

try this small change

`imp=imp.fit(data_1_group['datetime'])
data_1_group=imp.transform(data_1_group['datetime'])`

Though I m new to scikit myself, I am recommending the solution that worked for me. This is because

1) imp object needs to override to fit, as in the first line

2) it needs to fit and impute the same dataset, which in this case seems to be data_1_group['datetime']

I hope this helps